# Django, static files, and horizontal scalabilty

Tags: django, django-models, storage, scalability, horizontal-scaling

I am making a website in Django, and I am trying my best to make sure it is horizontally scalable.

Due to the application being horizontally scalable, I am unable to save Images that users upload locally, in the [media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/) folder.

I was wondering what are some ways I could save the images that the users upload, in such a way that would allow my application to be horizontal scalable?

I do have a MariaDB Galera Cluster that I use to store other data, but it seems like saving images in a shared database might not be the best idea due to performance reasons ([Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)).

If I attempt to use the media folder, are there any solutions that could sync storage (folder) between different instances of the application?

In general, what are some good practices for serving(download/upload) static content like images for horizontally scalable websites, and does Django provide anything to assist with this matter out of the box?

Comment: The solution is not to store media locally - use a service like Amazon S3 instead. There are loads of storage backends available for such services.

Comment: @solarissmoke Are there any localized alternatives to S3 buckets when it comes down to static files?